# How to switch from KDE to Xfce in OpenSuse

Tags: linux, window-manager, opensuse, xfce, gtk

I'm growing tired of Gnome and KDE and wish to move towards a more lightweight and customizable interface. I chose Xfce.

I downloaded all (I think) the packages related to Xfce but now I'm stumped as to how to actually run it as a default. I might want to try it a couple times first though. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have installed the software and dependencies through YaST, log out of your account. At the account selection screen you should seen a drop-down box that will let you choose your desktop environment.

Comment: That worked and now I'm in Xfce, however I feel that the window manager might still be kdm. I want to completely use xfce, is this possible?

Comment: What makes you think that KDM is the window manager? Any visual cues? There will be components of KDE running because some of the tools in OpenSUSE depend on KDE elements. If there is something that doesn't seem right, let me know and I can help you navigate through what may need to be done to prune some of the KDE bits.

Comment: @MaxMackie You could completely remove KDE, I think you will need some Gnome / GTK elements installed though.

Answer (score 0):

The Xfce file manager is thunar, and if I'm not mistaken, you should be able to use the thunar command if necessary from a shell.